# How to put variables in url address in applescript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to put the user search word into the url but it keeps thinking that the variable I have is the thing that I want to search...

```
set v to text returned of result
tell application "Google Chrome" to open 
location"https://www.google.co.in/search?q=v"
```

How do I make sure it knows that v is a variable and not part of the url?

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the strings with the `&` operator:

```
"https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & v
```

Be aware that you have to add percent escaping if `v` contains space characters.

Answer (score 0):

You ought not to use `open location`, which actually opens a URL in the system's default browser, regardless of which application you send the command to.  That's ok if your defaul browser is *Chrome*, but in that case, you can omit `tell application "Google Chrome" to`.

A more robust method is this:

```
    set v to the text returned of the result

    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        if the number of windows is 0 then make new window
        tell the front window to make new tab ¬
            with properties ¬
            {URL:"https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & v}
    end tell
```

Thankfully, using *AppleScript version* "2.7", on *macOS* "10.13.4", and *Chrome* "67" (and possibly earlier versions of any of these), you don't need to percent encode your string (`v`) to cater for spaces—this gets done automatically (but not for other special characters).